# removeView doesn't remove View immediately and destroys Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to dynamically remove some components in a `LinearLayout` in Android. The logic I have implemented is: If someone clicks a Button in my (Sidebar)`Fragment` I start an Animation that moves the clicked `Button` up and the Other Buttons out of the left side of the Display. The Animation triggers an `AnimationListener` that, after the Animation is complete, iterates over all Buttons in the Layout and removes all non clicked Buttons.
The Problem is: if I disable the Fade Out Animation and step in with the debugger i can see, that after `removeView()` the `Views` are still there.

The even bigger Problem is that my `Button` that should still be Visible (the clicked one) disappears and only shows up again, if I set X and Y Position manually at a later Time.

Is there any way i can "fix" the Button while removal and when does `removeView()` actually remove the View/update the Layout?

I already tried to remove all Views and then add the Button again with the same result.

Some snippets to clear things up a Bit:

```
//Start Animation over all Components
//Commented out the move outside animation to ensure the Layout doesn't get streched in this process
        for (mComponentIterator = mLayout.getChildCount() - 1; mComponentIterator >= 0; mComponentIterator--) {
            final ImageTextButton currentButton = (ImageTextButton) mLayout
                    .getChildAt(mComponentIterator);
            ObjectAnimator buttonAnimation;
            if (!currentButton.equals(pClickedButton)) {
//              buttonAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(currentButton, View.X, POSITION_OUTSIDE);
            } else {
//              buttonAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(currentButton, View.Y, POSITION_UPPER);
                animations.add( ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(currentButton, View.Y, POSITION_UPPER));
                currentButton.setFocused(true);
                mSelectedButton = currentButton;
            }
//          animations.add(buttonAnimation);
        }
            buttonAnimations.playTogether(animations);
        buttonAnimations.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
        buttonAnimations.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        buttonAnimations.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator arg0) {
                for (mComponentIterator = mLayout.getChildCount() - 1; mComponentIterator >= 0; mComponentIterator--) {
                    final ImageTextButton currentButton = (ImageTextButton) mLayout
                            .getChildAt(mComponentIterator);
                    if (currentButton.equals(mSelectedButton)) {
                        if (mCurrentFragment != null) {

                             //This changes the Layout in another 
                             mListener.onChangeLayoutRequest(R.id.maincontent, mCurrentFragment);
                        }
                    } else {
                                mLayout.removeView(currentButton);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        buttonAnimations.start();

//Callback when Activity is ready
mCurrentFragment.SetOnActivityCreatedListener(new OnActivityCreatedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity) {
                    Drawable grayMenuBackground = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.bg_menuitem);
                    Drawable coloredMenuBackground = grayMenuBackground.getConstantState()
                            .newDrawable();
                    coloredMenuBackground.setColorFilter(mSelectedMenuColor,
                            PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams rightGravityParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    rightGravityParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
                    rightGravityParams.weight = 0;

                    Drawable seperator = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.seperator_menu);
                    seperator.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, mSelectedButton.getWidth(), 1));

                    int insertIndex = 1;
                    for (Button menuButton : mCurrentFragment.getMenuItems()) {

                        //Some Button setupcode
                    mLayout.addView(menuButton, insertIndex++);
                }
                //Here the Button gets visible again
                mSelectedButton.setLayoutParams(rightGravityParams);
                mSelectedButton.setX(POSITION_LEFT);
                mSelectedButton.setY(POSITION_UPPER);
            }
        });
```

Im stuck at this problem for two days now. Currently the Buttons Animate in the right manner, then, right after the animation has finished, all Buttons dissapear(also the Clicked Button). Then, after 1/2sec. the other fragment needs to load, the clicked button appears again

**PS:** I already scheduled the removal with ''mLayout.post()'' with the same result

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you simply do:

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE) ;
```

Added some comments along your code.

```
//Start Animation over all Components
//Commented out the move outside animation to ensure the Layout doesn't get streched in this process
    for (mComponentIterator = mLayout.getChildCount() - 1; mComponentIterator >= 0; mComponentIterator--) {
        final ImageTextButton currentButton = (ImageTextButton) mLayout
                .getChildAt(mComponentIterator);
        ObjectAnimator buttonAnimation;
        if (!currentButton.equals(pClickedButton)) {
//              buttonAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(currentButton, View.X, POSITION_OUTSIDE);
        } else {
//              buttonAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(currentButton, View.Y, POSITION_UPPER);

            /* 
             * You say that you want to keep the clicked button, yet you
             * add it to the animations?
             */

            animations.add( ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(currentButton, View.Y, POSITION_UPPER));
            currentButton.setFocused(true);
            mSelectedButton = currentButton;
        }
//          animations.add(buttonAnimation);
    }
        buttonAnimations.playTogether(animations);
    buttonAnimations.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
    buttonAnimations.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    buttonAnimations.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator arg0) {
            for (mComponentIterator = mLayout.getChildCount() - 1; mComponentIterator >= 0; mComponentIterator--) {
                final ImageTextButton currentButton = (ImageTextButton) mLayout
                        .getChildAt(mComponentIterator);
                if (currentButton.equals(mSelectedButton)) {
                    if (mCurrentFragment != null) {

                         //This changes the Layout in another 

                         /*
                          * What exactly does this do and why does it have to
                          * be done (numberOfButtons - 1) times?
                          */

                         mListener.onChangeLayoutRequest(R.id.maincontent, mCurrentFragment);
                    }
                } else {

                            /*
                             * This does indeed only remove the non selected buttons 
                             * I think, but the animation is still applied to 
                             * the selcted button.
                             * So it makes sense that you have to reset X and Y 
                             * to see it again.
                             */ 
                            mLayout.removeView(currentButton);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    buttonAnimations.start();

//Callback when Activity is ready
mCurrentFragment.SetOnActivityCreatedListener(new OnActivityCreatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity) {
                Drawable grayMenuBackground = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.bg_menuitem);
                Drawable coloredMenuBackground = grayMenuBackground.getConstantState()
                        .newDrawable();
                coloredMenuBackground.setColorFilter(mSelectedMenuColor,
                        PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams rightGravityParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                rightGravityParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
                rightGravityParams.weight = 0;

                Drawable seperator = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.seperator_menu);
                seperator.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, mSelectedButton.getWidth(), 1));

                int insertIndex = 1;
                for (Button menuButton : mCurrentFragment.getMenuItems()) {

                    //Some Button setupcode
                mLayout.addView(menuButton, insertIndex++);
            }
            //Here the Button gets visible again
            mSelectedButton.setLayoutParams(rightGravityParams);
            mSelectedButton.setX(POSITION_LEFT);
            mSelectedButton.setY(POSITION_UPPER);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Same result, exept that the Button then appears **under** the extra added buttons (The ones added in the ''onActivityCreated'' callback. The really strange thing is: what happens with the button after removal of the other Buttons.

Comment: Sounds strange.. when you call mLayout.addView(menuButton, insertIndex++);, are you then referencing the removed button too? Thinking that it possibly should be left out here too, if you do reference it.

Comment: no, ''mCurrentFragment.getMenuItems()'' just gets back a list of extra buttons. all that happens to the ''mSelectedButton'' is in the code above.

Since I don't delete The Button I want to keep i start the ''insertIndex'' at 1 (I think after removal of all other Buttons, ''mSelectedButton'' should be at index 0?

Comment: Your code is still not clear to me. Added your code with some comments

Comment: I'm currently in the Process of refactoring and commenting. I have a current clone of this class here: http://pastebin.com/HqEbrNMj . To clear some things up: My main Activity consists of 2 Fragments. One on the left, the other on the right. The left one is the "Main Menu". Each Fragment on the right can populate a List of Buttons to add to the Left Menu. So I start the app, have my 6 Main Menu Buttons. If I click one, the clicked Button moves up, the others disappear and some 'Context related' Buttons Pop Up.

Comment: (Example: Main Menu: Navigation, Settings --> Click:Navigation --> Main Menu: Navigation, Enter Adress, Enter POI. Hope this clears things up. 
**PS:** currently all the magic happens in OnClick

Comment: Sorry just saw your edited Post:
Yes I apply an Animation to the clicked Button, but not one that moves the Button out. It Moves the Button to the Position of the old, topmost button. (And this works quite niceley and the Button is where it should be until some time after ''onAnimationEnded''.
The Change in Layout should only happen once, but i refactored that bit in the Code I Pasted and moved it outside the Loop.

Comment: I just understood what you meant with adding the Animation. Sorry i messed this up in the Code Snipped, but on Pastebin it is correctedwith still the same result

Comment: But the main problem is that the Views are not removed correctly, right? .. what happens if you change mLayout.removeView(currentButton); to instead calling mLayout.removeAllViews(); and mLayout.addView(mSelectedButton); after animation end. Hence, removing the whole for loop.

Comment: Just as a debug step, I am curious if there is an issue with the references or the like.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this doesn't help either. Even if it is a nice simplification of the Code. Same result. Button disappears and appears when I set the X and Y manually. 
I already stepped in the removeView with a debugger. The Views get removed correctly from mChilds in the LinearLayout but are still Visible on the Screen, even if removeView() invokes invalidate(). 
If i set a breakpoint right after addView(mCurrentButton), mLayout->mChildreen is empty but I still can see the buttons.
LinearLayout doesnt seem to enqueue any redrawal in removeAllViews().
Is invalidate() asynchronus?

Comment: I just added a OnHierarchyChangeListener to mLayout and set a Breakpoint to onChildRemoved, but it seems that this gets called right after removeAllViews(), so all Buttons are still Visible at the Time the code reaches this line.
I have to set the X and Y coordinates of mSelectedButton right after the mLayout gets refreshed and my Buttons disappear, but I can't find that in the Code. Is there any function to invoke (not to schedule) a complete redraw, remeasure, refresh of a View?

Comment: Another idea. How about you accept this behaviour and never remove any buttons, simply redesign them depending on need. That is, always have the maximum amount of buttons being either off screen or showing, perhaps saved in a list, I dont know. Then when needed simply set new text and overwrite onClickListener.

Comment: This won't do it for a couple of reasons:
My extended Buttons have a different height than the menubuttons, so more of them fin on the screen.
The order of the Buttons is important; I need the pressed Button to be the first.
But if none has a Idea I will simply redesign the Animations